# How to append a header row in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, sidebar

I'm passing some properties(id and name) of multiple features from a `leaflet` map to a dynamic `html` table in a `sidebar`.

```
var demo2 =  "<table class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
             "<tr>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.id + "</td>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.Name + "</td>\n" +
             "</tr>\n" +
             "</table>";
                  for (var i = 0; i < demo2.length; i++) {
                      if (demo2 !== 0) {
                         return function() {
                            (document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home").innerHTML += demo2);
```

I'm looking for a way to append a header row at the top of the `html` table.
If I include the header row in the variable, I get a header row inserted in between each data row. Which is clearly NOT what I want.

```
var demo2 =  "<table class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
             "<tr>\n" +
             "<th>" + id + "</th>\n" +
             "<th>" + Name + "</th>\n" +
             "</tr>\n" +
             "<tr>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.id + "</td>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.Name + "</td>\n" +
             "</tr>\n" +
             "</table>";
                  for (var i = 0; i < demo2.length; i++) {
                      if (demo2 !== 0) {
                         return function() {
                            (document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home").innerHTML += demo2);
```

I've thought about using a separate variable for the header row, but I don't know how to add both variables to the `innerHTML`.

```
//this doesn't work either//
var demo1 =  "<table class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
             "<tr>\n" +
             "<th>" + id + "</th>\n" +
             "<th>" + Name + "</th>\n" +
             "</tr>\n" +
var demo2 =  "<table class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
             "<tr>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.id + "</td>\n" +
             "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.Name + "</td>\n" +
             "</tr>\n" +
             "</table>";
                  for (var i = 0; i < demo2.length; i++) {
                      if (demo2 !== 0) {
                         return function() {
                            (document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home").innerHTML += demo1+demo2);
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this.., or is there a better way all together?

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't clear to me.
Anyway, You can define the `demo2` variable with a starting value that will not be repeated, then add the dynamic HTML into `demo2` variable, after that add the end of the table, Finally use the `innerHTML` to append it.

```js
let demo2 = `<table class="w3-table-all" style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>${id}</th>
    <th>${Name}</th>
  </tr>`;
for (var i = 0; I < .....) {
  demo2 += `<tr>
    <td>${YOUR_DYNAMIC_VARIABLE}</td>
    <td>${YOUR_DYNAMIC_VARIABLE}</td> 
  </tr>`;
}

demo2 += `</table>`;

document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home").innerHTML += demo2
```

The result will be one table with one table header and repeated table rows for your data.

Comment: using your code, I'm still getting the header row in between the data rows. But let me try to adjust my code based on your logic of putting a static header row at the beginning and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this a while back, so I just thought I should post the answer in case someone else has a similar problem.

The idea is to create a separate table to handle the header row and give it an `ID="table"`; then, first append the same header table to the `sidebar`;
after that, you append the dynamic table to the header table using the table id.

```
var demo1 =  "<table id='table' class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
         "<tr>\n" +
         "<th>" + id + "</th>\n" +
         "<th>" + Name + "</th>\n" +
         "</tr>\n" +
         "</table>";
            document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home").innerHTML = demo1;

var demo2 =  "<table class='w3-table-all' style=width:\'100%\' border=\'1\'>\n" +
         "<tr>\n" +
         "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.id + "</td>\n" +
         "<td>" + layer.feature.properties.Name + "</td>\n" +
         "</tr>\n" +
         "</table>";
              for (var i = 0; i < demo2.length; i++) {
                  if (demo2 !== 0) {
                     return function() {
                        (document.querySelector("#sidebar #sidebar-content #home #table").innerHTML += demo2);
```